# New sliding door with stucco behind vinyl siding

Tags: repair, doors, windows, replacement, stucco

Has anyone had experience treating old (1948) stucco (3/4” stucco, metal lath, tar paper, ship lap) as wall board when installing new sliding doors or windows? I have vinyl siding that is on furring strips that are ramshot and glued onto the stucco. There is no continuous housewrap to speak of between the vinyl and stucco, just some foam insulation between furring. Considering adhering a new door straight to the stucco, flashing tape, sealant, etc. Any real world experience guys have had? Am I crazy and should just breakout the stucco and patch?

Comment: With the metal lath breaking it out is a major job then you have a gap to fill. I have always repaired stucco but breaking it up may not be a good idea.

Comment: @EdBeal Do you just cut the stucco out with a masonry saw and repair?